# How to use the automatic set up feature in Visual Studio and how reference a file location automatically

Tags: c#, file, installation, directory

Okay, so hopefully the issue was explained properly in the title, but if not then basically in my program I have an array which is loaded with a ton of data straight off a **.csv** file when the program is launched and so I need to make it so that when the set up is run the file destination of the .csv in the code is correct.

Otherwise it won't load the array with anything and so ultimately my question is how do I do that? Here are some screenshots of what I've already tried, and some snippets of code, if anyone could even point me in the direction of a YT video that may even be helpful enough, thanks StackOverflow users. https://pastebin.com/cEmZxujx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check the reference with

System.IO.File.Exists("filename")

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben J, I can see the file exists in the location referenced in the code simply from navigating to the place I told it to go during the installation, hence my confusion. http://prntscr.com/epli64 Also I only know a small amount of c# as I am still in the very early stages of learning, what exactly does System.IO.File.Exists("filename"); do, i just added it below the original reference of the file location, it did not change how the code works, not from what i can see from running this installation anyway.

Comment: Sys.tem.File.Exists just check that the file exists.  You'd need to use it in something like 

if(!System.IO.File.Exists("filename")
  throw error message

Comment: OK, I gave that a go and the file definitely exists, it just for some reason does not want to read the data from this file I think, would there be any reason this would happen?

Comment: I can't see enough of your code to know what's happening when the file is read.  Is there any sort of error?  Maybe you could show the code that reads the file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Q7Cjk9rN  Here is the code you asked for, i am just stumped as to why it doesnt read that properly, it reads the other directories fine (Except the F:\ one, that is on a separate machine). Edit: Correction it still reads the one from C:\ when i dont run it from the installer and instead just run it straight from vis studio.

Comment: Hmm.  If there's no error message from the try block and system.IO.File.Exists returns true, then I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Alright man, thank you for all the help anyway, I appreciate it.